# Comunicação com o PagSeguro

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Preciso fazer uma aplicação a qual comunique com o pagseguro.

Ou seja ele faz a compra, eu envio e depois preciso automaticamente atualizar no banco quando efetuar o pagamento.

Até enviar para o pagseguro tenho uma noção. A minha dúvida é como saber quando o cliente realizou o pagamento. E também como testar isso (não precisar efetuar pagamentos).

Com referência ao 
[PagSeguro para .Net - Controles de Integração e Servidor de Teste](https://code.google.com/p/pagsegurodotnet/)

Consegui rodar o com esse código:

```
<form target="pagseguro" method="post"
              action="https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/checkout/checkout.jhtml">
            <input type="hidden" name="email_cobranca"
                   value="email@email.com" />
            <input type="hidden" name="tipo" value="CBR" />
            <input type="hidden" name="moeda" value="BRL" />
            <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="@Model.ID" />
            <input type="hidden" name="item_descr"
                   value="@Model.Nome" />
            <input type="hidden" name="item_quant" value="1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="item_valor" value="1.00" />
            <input type="image" name="submit"
                   src="https://p.simg.uol.com.br/out/pagseguro/i/botoes/pagamentos/99x61-comprar-assina.gif"
                   alt="Pague com PagSeguro - é rápido, grátis e seguro!" />
        </form>
```

No ambiente de teste roda normal, porém no ambiente do pagseguro, dá erro ao receber o post.

Meu código:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Retorno(FormCollection collection)
    {
        var teste2 = new Teste()
        {
            Cod = "TransacaoID",
            Id = 354684,
            Status = "StatusTransacao"
        };

        AddTeste(teste2); //utilizei para saber se chega até aqui!

        string TransacaoID = collection["TransacaoID"];
        string StatusTransacao = collection["StatusTransacao"];

        var teste = new Teste()
        {
            Cod = TransacaoID,
            Id = 354684,
            Status = StatusTransacao
        };


        AddTeste(teste);

        return null;
    }
```

Até o AddTeste(teste2), ele chega, porém no AddTeste(teste), não chega.

*Não tem como dar Debug porque preciso subir o projeto para uma URL válida no pagseguro

Comment: Felipe o Pag Seguro aconselha no próprio blog deles a criação de pagamentos de R$ 1,00 (senão me engano) para ser pago com boleto! Este procedimento já irá gerar uma mudança de status no sistema deles que o seu app poderá receber e testar. A primeira coisa que te aconselho é verificar se você está configurando corretamente a url de retorno do seu site, pois é nela que você fará toda a mágica acontecer, se o endereço não estiver bem configurado na plataforma doo Pag Seguro você não receberá as respostas para atualização do seu sistema.

Answer (score 13):

Montei um pacote NuGet que faz os envios ao PagSeguro, com base no GitHub deles:

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Uol.PagSeguro

[Os fontes estão aqui](https://github.com/pagseguro/dotnet).

## Criando um Pedido

Estes são os passos para criar um pedido básico. Os demais exemplos devem ser considerados usando o exemplo abaixo como base.

```
    // Essa variável define se é o ambiente de teste ou produção.
    const bool isSandbox = true;

    EnvironmentConfiguration.ChangeEnvironment(isSandbox);

    try
    {
        var credentials = PagSeguroConfiguration.Credentials(isSandbox);

        // Instanciar uma nova requisição de pagamento
        var payment = new PaymentRequest {Currency = Currency.Brl};

        // Adicionar produtos
        payment.Items.Add(new Item("0001", "Notebook Prata", 1, 2430.00m));
        payment.Items.Add(new Item("0002", "Notebook Rosa", 2, 150.99m));

        // Código que identifica o pagamento
        payment.Reference = "REF1234";

        // Informações de entrega
        payment.Shipping = new Shipping
        {
            ShippingType = ShippingType.Sedex,
            Cost = 10.00m,
            Address = new Address(
                "BRA",
                "SP",
                "Sao Paulo",
                "Jardim Paulistano",
                "01452002",
                "Av. Brig. Faria Lima",
                "1384",
                "5o andar"
                )
        };

        // Informações do remetente
        payment.Sender = new Sender(
            "Joao Comprador", 
            "comprador@uol.com.br", 
            new Phone("11", "56273440")
        );

        // URL a redirecionar o usuário após pagamento
        payment.RedirectUri = new Uri("http://www.lojamodelo.com.br");

        // Informações extras para identificar o pagamento.
        // Essas informações são livres para adicionar o que for necessário.
        payment.AddMetaData(MetaDataItemKeys.GetItemKeyByDescription("CPF do passageiro"), "123.456.789-09", 1);
        payment.AddMetaData("PASSENGER_PASSPORT", "23456", 1);

        // Outra forma de definir os parâmetros de pagamento.
        payment.AddParameter("senderBirthday", "07/05/1980");
        payment.AddIndexedParameter("itemColor", "verde", 1);
        payment.AddIndexedParameter("itemId", "0003", 3);
        payment.AddIndexedParameter("itemDescription", "Mouse", 3);
        payment.AddIndexedParameter("itemQuantity", "1", 3);
        payment.AddIndexedParameter("itemAmount", "200.00", 3);

        var senderCpf = new SenderDocument(Documents.GetDocumentByType("CPF"), "12345678909"); 
        payment.Sender.Documents.Add(senderCpf);

        var paymentRedirectUri = payment.Register(credentials);

        Console.WriteLine("URL do pagamento : " + paymentRedirectUri);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    catch (PagSeguroServiceException exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exception.Message + "\n");

        foreach (var element in exception.Errors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(element + "\n");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

### Criar Pedido com Assinatura

Aqui se faz um lançamento de assinatura dentro de uma venda normal, que peça ao usuário a aprovação.

```
        var now = DateTime.Now;

        payment.PreApproval = new PreApproval
        {
            Charge = Charge.Manual,
            Name = "Seguro contra roubo do Notebook",
            AmountPerPayment = 100.00m,
            MaxAmountPerPeriod = 100.00m,
            Details = string.Format("Todo dia {0} será cobrado o valor de {1} referente ao seguro contra roubo do Notebook.", now.Day, payment.PreApproval.AmountPerPayment.ToString("C2")),
            Period = Period.Monthly,
            DayOfMonth = now.Day,
            InitialDate = now,
            FinalDate = now.AddMonths(6),
            MaxTotalAmount = 600.00m,
            MaxPaymentsPerPeriod = 1
        };
```

### Cancelar Assinatura

```
    // Tendo um código de transação, insira no segundo argumento.
    var cancelResult = PreApprovalService.CancelPreApproval(credentials, "3DFAD3123412340334A96F9136C38804");
```

### Verificar Status de uma Transação

```
    // Transação Normal
    var transaction = NotificationService.CheckTransaction(credentials, "766B9C-AD4B044B04DA-77742F5FA653-E1AB24", false);

    // Transação Tipo Assinatura
    var preApprovalTransaction = NotificationService.CheckTransaction(credentials, "3DFAD3123412340334A96F9136C38804", true);
```

### Buscar Transação por Código de Transação

```
    var preApprovalTransaction = TransactionSearchService.SearchByCode(credentials, "3DFAD3123412340334A96F9136C38804", true);
```

### Buscar Transações por Intervalo de Datas

```
        // Definindo a data de ínicio da consulta 
        var initialDate = new DateTime(2014, 07, 01, 08, 50, 0);

        // Definindo a data de término da consulta
        var finalDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-5);

        // Definindo o número máximo de resultados por página
        const int maxPageResults = 10;

        // Definindo o número da página
        const int pageNumber = 1;

        // Realizando a consulta
        var result =
            TransactionSearchService.SearchByDate(
                credentials,
                initialDate,
                finalDate,
                pageNumber,
                maxPageResults,
                false);

        if (result.Transactions.Count <= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Nenhuma transação");
        }

        if (result.PreApprovals.Count <= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Nenhuma assinatura");
        }

        foreach (var transaction in result.Transactions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Começando listagem de transações - \n");
            Console.WriteLine(transaction.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(" - Terminando listagem de transações ");
        }

        foreach (var transaction in result.PreApprovals)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Começando listagem de assinaturas - \n");
            Console.WriteLine(transaction.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(" - Terminando listagem de assinaturas ");
        }
```

Comment: Opa Cigano, parabéns pelo trabalho. Como eu consigo alterar o local onde fica armazenado o arquivo PagSeguroConfig.xml. Eu recebo o seguinte erro: "Não foi possível localizar uma parte do caminho 'C:\\Configuration\\PagSeguroConfig.xml'." Caso eu coloque nesse caminho funciona normalmente, mas quando eu colocar o projeto no Azure por exemplo, eu terei problemas. Quero adicionar esse arquivo no meu projeto e referencia-lo a ele, como posso fazer isso? Desde já agradeço!

Comment: Preciso atualizar o pacote. Farei isso hoje, se der tempo.

Comment: Beleza cara! Valeu! ;)

Comment: Oi, e pra usar o botão de doação e depois resgatar o valor total ou de cada transação? No meu caso é em php. Obrigado!

Comment: @MarcelloInfoweb Por favor, faça outra pergunta na tag de PHP.

Comment: @KleytonSantos Jovem, desculpe a demora. Atualizei o pacote hoje.

Comment: Nada, Tudo bem! Atualmente eu comecei a usar o PayPal... Mas ainda sim o seu ajuste foi muito válido! Obrigado @CiganoMorrisonMendez :)

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez esta linha de código, URL do pagamento seria a tela do meu site que o usuário irá informar os dados de pagamento? tipo cartão boleto etc? 
Console.WriteLine("URL do pagamento : " + paymentRedirectUri);

Comment: Sim, a tela do PagSeguro que esses dados são preenchidos.

Comment: eu travei nessa linha **Console.WriteLine("URL do pagamento : " + paymentRedirectUri);** e então abri uma [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/163576/integra%C3%A7%C3%A3o-api-pagseguro/163597?noredirect=1#comment336719_163597) aqui, que foi respondido que esta linha retorna um console em dos para o usuário dar entrada dos dados, o que realmente precisaria para que fizesse o envio destas informações para o pagseguro? acredito que o erro está aqui.

Answer (score 6):

Felipe,

Você pode utilizar o **PagSeguro TestServer** para fins de teste. Para saber quando o usuário realizou o pagamento existe a URL de retorno (callback) que você configura que será o endereço que ele deve retornar caso tenha efetuado a transação.

Segue o link abaixo explicando melhor como configurar e usar o servidor local. Um amigo utilizou ele no TCC e conseguiu normalmente simular o ambiente real.

[PagSeguro para .Net - Controles de Integração e Servidor de Teste](https://code.google.com/p/pagsegurodotnet/)

Comment: Fiz umas alterações na pergunta com algumas dúvidas que surgiu do tutorial.