# Erro ao realizar pedido com API do PagSeguro

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xml

Ao tentar realizar a criação do pagamento, recebo o seguinte erro. Estou utilizando o seguinte pacote: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Uol.PagSeguro

> Additional information: Por motivo de segurança, o DTD é proibido
>   neste documento XML. Para habilitar o processamento do DTD, defina a
>   propriedade DtdProcessing em XmlReaderSettings como Parse e passe as
>   configurações para o método XmlReader.Create.

Estou utilizando um código de testes oferecido por Cigano [neste tópico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/37090/17825):

A exceção é levantada na seguinte linha:

```
var paymentRedirectUri = payment.Register(credentials);
```

Também estou utilizando o ambiente *sandbox* do PagSeguro, e já verifiquei as *credentials* e o URL enviada (antes estava dando erro 401).

Consigo contornar o erro descrito acima editando o código da API, no seguinte bloco de código:

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ProhibitDtd = false;
using (XmlReader reader =     XmlReader.Create(response.GetResponseStream(), settings))
{
  //Codigo pagseguro
}
```

Contudo, ao realizar esta alteração, obtenho o seguinte erro quando a API realiza a leitura do XML

> Additional information: Caractere inválido na codificação fornecida.
>   Linha 20, posição 48.

Comment: Dê mais informações de como está fazendo.

Comment: Pergunta atualizada. Tem alguma outra informação que eu possa dar que seja util?

Comment: Não sei porque não entendo do assunto, mas sei que mostrar só o erro não ajuda muito. Sempre é bom colocar o que já fez.

Comment: O que foi realizado é exatamente o que está na questão respondida pelo Cigano. O código inclusive é o mesmo, apenas para teste da integração da API. Contudo, este erro está surgindo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caractere inválido, isso soa como um XML que trabalha com ANSI (ou `iso-8859-1`/`window-1252`) porém acabam retornando dados com caracteres `UTF-8`, é só um teoria, mas talvez você deva verificar as codificações retornadas pelo XML. Para fazer está verificação tente analisar o conteudo de `response.GetResponseStream()`.

Note que se o seu XML usa `UTF-8` (ou outra codificação UNICODE) e o cabeçalho não possuir algo como `<?xml charset="UTF-8" ?>` será bem provável que este erro ocorra.

Se o documento possuir caracteres equivalentes do `latin1` e não houver `charset` definido para `iso-8859-1` ou `windows-1252`, este erro também pode ocorrer.

Analisando o código do usuário Cigano, eu não encontrei nada referente ao `XmlReader` que você citou, então irei presumir que isto é uma aplicação sua.

Uma solução anternativa seria usar esta propriedade:

```
public bool CheckCharacters { get; set; }
```

Definindo como `false` o `XmlReaderSettings.CheckCharacters` você irá desligar a verificação dos caracteres.

Segue documentação:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.checkcharacters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx