# Erro ao Receber POST no PagSeguro

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma plataforma que realiza compras via formulário do PagSeguro. O problema é que só estou recebendo o POST no qual o `StatusTransacao` está como "Aguardando Pagamento", ou seja, no caso de um boleto gerado. Se a compra foi aprovada, não recebo POST e na plataforma do PagSeguro visualizo um erro 500.

Segue abaixo meu código:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult RetornoPagamento(FormCollection collection)
        {
            string Token = "";
            string Pagina = "https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/pagseguro-ws/checkout/NPI.jhtml";
            string Dados = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.ToString() + "&Comando=validar" + "&Token=" + Token;

            System.Net.HttpWebRequest req = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Pagina);

            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentLength = Dados.Length;
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            System.IO.StreamWriter stOut = new System.IO.StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));
            stOut.Write(Dados);
            stOut.Close();

            System.IO.StreamReader stIn = new System.IO.StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));
            string Result = stIn.ReadToEnd();
            stIn.Close();

            if (Result == "VERIFICADO")
            {

                SqlConnection MinhaConexao = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BancoDados"].ConnectionString);
                MinhaConexao.Open();
                string query = "";

                CursoAlunoAplicacao bdCursoAluno;
                bdCursoAluno = CursoAlunoAplicacaoConstrutor.CursoAlunoAplicacaoEF();
                var VerificarCursoAluno = bdCursoAluno.ListarTodos().Where(x => x.Transacao == collection["TransacaoID"]);

                if (VerificarCursoAluno.Count() >= 1)
                {
                    if (collection["StatusTransacao"] == "Aprovado")
                    {
                        query = "UPDATE CursoRapido_CursoAluno SET Pagamento = 1 WHERE Transacao = '" + collection["TransacaoID"] + "'";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (collection["StatusTransacao"] == "Aprovado")
                    {
                        query = "INSERT INTO CursoRapido_CursoAluno (Pagamento,Aluno_ID,Cursos_ID,Transacao) VALUES (1, '" + collection["Referencia"] + "'," + collection["ProdID_1"] + ",'" + collection["TransacaoID"] + "')";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        query = "INSERT INTO CursoRapido_CursoAluno (Pagamento,Aluno_ID,Cursos_ID,Transacao) VALUES (0, '" + collection["Referencia"] + "'," + collection["ProdID_1"] + ",'" + collection["TransacaoID"] + "')";
                    }
                }

                SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(query, MinhaConexao);
                comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MinhaConexao.Close();
            }

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult RetornoPagamento()
        {
            string url = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
            var ID_Transacao = url.Substring(url.IndexOf("ID_Transacao="));
            ID_Transacao = ID_Transacao.Replace("ID_Transacao=", "");
            ID_Transacao = ID_Transacao.Replace("-", "");

            CursoAlunoAplicacao bdCursoAluno;
            bdCursoAluno = CursoAlunoAplicacaoConstrutor.CursoAlunoAplicacaoEF();

            if (bdCursoAluno.ListarTodos().Where(x => x.Transacao == ID_Transacao).Count() > 0)
            {
                var IDAtual = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

                var CursoComprado = bdCursoAluno.ListarTodos().Where(x => x.Aluno.ID == int.Parse(IDAtual)).LastOrDefault();
                string Parametro = IDAtual + "-" + CursoComprado.Cursos.ID;

                return RedirectToAction("CursoDetalhe", new { id = Parametro });
            }

            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("AguardandoPagamento");
            }

        }
```

Comment: Por que não [usa o pacote do PagSeguro](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Uol.PagSeguro/)?

Comment: Porque como é uma aplicação simples e até mesmo sem carrinho, achei que assim seria mais fácil

Comment: Aparentemente é, mas já deu pra ver que você não tem como obter o erro. [Veja esta resposta pra saber como usar o pacote](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35093/comunica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-o-pagseguro/37090#37090).

Comment: Eu visualizei o link que me passou mas não encontrei lá o modo para trabalhar com o retorno. O envio está ok, está funcionando no meu código atual. Só não entendo porque o POST da erro 500 ao tentar acessar minha action RetornoPagamento

Comment: De cabeça não lembro, mas acho que é no objeto `payment`. Vou conferir pra você quando puder

Comment: Ok, estarei aguardando. Obrigado.

Comment: @RafaelBarbosa só pra ter certeza que você entende como funciona o PagSeguro, o POST que ele envia ao seu servidor é comunicação servidor com servidor, não funciona do lado "cliente". Você já tentou o ambiente de teste do PagSeguro?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Eu entendo isso, por isso tenho meu método RetornoPagamento com [HttpPost], para receber o POST pós confirmação e executar minha query. O problema é que só recebo POST na hora que a compra é feita via boleto.

Comment: @RafaelBarbosa era só pra ter certeza :) me diz você está usando o ambiente de teste? Vou ver se consigo testar o seu código hoje

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Ah sim. Então, para ser sincero eu usei o ambiente de teste até receber algo positivo, que no caso foi a interação que obtive quando gerei boleto, depois disso continuei na teimosia partindo do ponto de que meu código estava se comunicando com o PagSeguro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz o envio de um e-mail com cada situação do processo de compra e resposta do servidor do PagSeguro.

Com isso constatei que o problema era com o condicional `if (Result == "VERIFICADO")`. Agora o problema está resolvido.

Segue abaixo o código:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult RetornoPagamento(FormCollection collection)
        {
            string Mensagem;
            Mensagem = "Entrou";
            Helpers.Email enviarEmail = new Helpers.Email();
            enviarEmail.Enviar(Mensagem);


            string Token = "";
            string Pagina = "https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/pagseguro-ws/checkout/NPI.jhtml";
            string Dados = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.ToString() + "&Comando=validar" + "&Token=" + Token;
            enviarEmail.Enviar(Dados);

            System.Net.HttpWebRequest req = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(Pagina);

            req.Method = "POST";
            req.ContentLength = Dados.Length;
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            System.IO.StreamWriter stOut = new System.IO.StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));
            stOut.Write(Dados);
            stOut.Close();

            System.IO.StreamReader stIn = new System.IO.StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));
            string Result = stIn.ReadToEnd();
            stIn.Close();


                SqlConnection MinhaConexao = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BancoDados"].ConnectionString);
                MinhaConexao.Open();
                string query = "";

                CursoAlunoAplicacao bdCursoAluno;
                bdCursoAluno = CursoAlunoAplicacaoConstrutor.CursoAlunoAplicacaoEF();
                var VerificarCursoAluno = bdCursoAluno.ListarTodos().Where(x => x.Transacao == collection["TransacaoID"]);

                if (VerificarCursoAluno.Count() >= 1)
                {
                    Mensagem = "Já existe";
                    enviarEmail.Enviar(Mensagem);
                    if (collection["StatusTransacao"] == "Aprovado")
                    {
                        Mensagem = "Aprovado";
                        enviarEmail.Enviar(Mensagem);
                        query = "UPDATE CursoRapido_CursoAluno SET Pagamento = 1 WHERE Transacao = '" + collection["TransacaoID"] + "'";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Mensagem = "Não existe ainda";
                    enviarEmail.Enviar(Mensagem);
                    if (collection["StatusTransacao"] == "Aprovado")
                    {
                        Mensagem = "Aprovado Boleto";
                        enviarEmail.Enviar(Mensagem);
                        query = "UPDATE CursoRapido_CursoAluno SET Pagamento = 1 WHERE Transacao = '" + collection["TransacaoID"] + "'";
                    }
                    else if (collection["StatusTransacao"] == "Aguardando Pagto" || collection["StatusTransacao"] == "Em Análise")
                    {
                        Mensagem = "Boleto Gerado";
                        enviarEmail.Enviar(Mensagem);
                        query = "INSERT INTO CursoRapido_CursoAluno (Pagamento,Aluno_ID,Cursos_ID,Transacao) VALUES (0, '" + collection["Referencia"] + "'," + collection["ProdID_1"] + ",'" + collection["TransacaoID"] + "')";
                    }
                }

                SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(query, MinhaConexao);
                comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MinhaConexao.Close();
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult RetornoPagamento()
        {
            string url = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
            var ID_Transacao = url.Substring(url.IndexOf("ID_Transacao="));
            ID_Transacao = ID_Transacao.Replace("ID_Transacao=", "");
            ID_Transacao = ID_Transacao.Replace("-", "");

            CursoAlunoAplicacao bdCursoAluno;
            bdCursoAluno = CursoAlunoAplicacaoConstrutor.CursoAlunoAplicacaoEF();

            if (bdCursoAluno.ListarTodos().Where(x => x.Transacao == ID_Transacao).Count() > 0)
            {
                var IDAtual = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;

                var CursoComprado = bdCursoAluno.ListarTodos().Where(x => x.Aluno.ID == int.Parse(IDAtual)).LastOrDefault();
                string Parametro = IDAtual + "-" + CursoComprado.Cursos.ID;

                return RedirectToAction("CursoDetalhe", new { id = Parametro });
            }

            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("AguardandoPagamento");
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Rafael, sugiro que gere um novo Token pois pode gerar problema na segurança da aplicação.
Além disso não divulgue seu o endereço do site pois a aplicação não verifica se é VERIFICADO então pode receber facilmente um POST externo.

Comment: Atualizei minha resposta e retirei o Token, realmente não havia me atentado a isso. Sobre a questão da divulgação, verifiquei toda a pergunta para garantir que não existisse ligações com minha plataforma.
Anteriormente já havia sanado minha dúvida relativa a pergunta, porém, como me ajudou a pensar nas questões de segurança e contando com o fato de que a gratificação não pode ser cancelada, estarei te concedendo.

Comment: Ok, fico agradecido.