# API de Notificações PagSeguro

Tags: c#, asp.net

Senhores, boa noite!

Estou fazendo uma integração com o pagseguro para o meu site.

Configurei a pagina para receber a notificação sempre que o status dela for alterada conforme o código abaixo.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var notificationCode = Request.QueryString["notificationCode"];
            var token = "***";
            var email = "********@live.com";

            if (notificationCode != null)
            {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
            WebRequest.Create("https://ws.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v3/transactions/notifications/" + notificationCode + "?email=" + email + "&token=" + token);
            request.Method = "GET";
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            }
        }
```

Faço uma verificação se existe o codigo de notificação, se existir, ele faz um redirect na pagina do pagseguro requisitando o XML desta notificação. Mas penso que desta forma não está correto.

Gostaria de uma ajuda para fazer uma requisição do tipo GET no pagseguro, com o link, e receber este XML, além disto, guardar o status do pagamento e a referencia em uma variavel qualquer... (var status e var referencia por exemplo)

O status fica dentro do node transaction

```
<transaction>      
        <status>3</status>    
</transaction>
```

Alguem por favor, me ajude?

Comment: Já olhou a documentação do próprio PagSeguro (https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/guia-de-integracao/tutorial-da-biblioteca-pagseguro-netframework.html)? Eles possuem uma API para auxiliar neste tipo de situação.

Comment: Este é o jeito difícil de fazer. [Nesta resposta, ensino vários casos de uso envolvendo a API](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35093/comunica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-o-pagseguro/37090#37090). Basta instalar o pacote NuGet e alterar os exemplos. Se precisar de mais ajuda, pode me responder por comentário que aprimoro a resposta.