# Asp.NET + PagSeguro

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Bom dia, cheguei no momento em que precisa adicionar as formas de pagamento.
e eu quero por Pagseguro.
Qual o primeiro passo pra fazer isso?
Onde tenho que implementar as classes do pagseguro no meu projeto?
Devo separar em um novo projeto?
N achei videos ensinando.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Comunicação com o PagSeguro](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35093/20615)

Answer (score 4):

O PagSeguro possui [este tutorial](https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/guia-de-integracao/tutorial-da-biblioteca-pagseguro-netframework.html) explicando o que precisa para utilizar sua biblioteca.

O GitHub oficial do projeto [pode ser visto aqui](https://github.com/pagseguro/dotnet).

[Esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/37090/20615) do @CiganoMorrizonMendez possui um "pequeno tutorial" de como realizar o que deseja.

Existem também a forma do [botão de pagamento](https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/desenvolvedor/botoes_de_pagamento.jhtml), onde você direciona o cliente para o site do PagSeguro. Essa opção não necessita de programação e você personaliza pelo site do PagSeguro.