# Como criar assinatura em asp.net com pagseguro

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, api, pagamento-online

Olá já pesquisei por todos os lados e não achei como integrar uma assinatura dentro do meu sistema em asp.net mvc com o pagseguro. Usei esse código e meu retorno não está dando certo quando adiciono esse preapproval !

```
 //**********************Inicio do procedimento para gerar uma compra pela API do pagseguro
                    DateTime now = new DateTime();
                    var payment = new PaymentRequest();

                    payment.Items.Add(new Item("0001", "Notebook Prata", 1, 2430.00m));
                    payment.Items.Add(new Item("0002", "Mochila", 1, 150.99m));

                    payment.Sender = new Sender("José Comprador","comprador@uol.com.br",new Phone("11","56273440"));

                    payment.PreApproval = new PreApproval
                    {
                        Charge = Charge.Auto,
                        Name = "Seguro contra roubo do Notebook",
                        AmountPerPayment = 100.00m,
                        MaxAmountPerPeriod = 100.00m,
                        Details = string.Format("test"),
                        Period = Period.Monthly,
                        DayOfMonth = now.Day,
                        InitialDate = now,
                        FinalDate = now.AddMonths(6),
                        MaxTotalAmount = 600.00m,
                        MaxPaymentsPerPeriod = 1,

                    };

                    payment.Currency = Currency.Brl;

                    SenderDocument senderCPF = new SenderDocument(Documents.GetDocumentByType("CPF"), "12345678909");
                    payment.Sender.Documents.Add(senderCPF);
                    AccountCredentials credentials = new AccountCredentials("admin@email.com","ABC1234DEF");

                    Uri paymentRedirectUri = payment.Register(credentials);

                    return Redirect(paymentRedirectUri.AbsoluteUri);


                    //**************************************************************************
```

Já olhei o [método do @CiganoMorissonMendez](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35093/comunica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-o-pagseguro/37090#37090) que ajudo bastante porem é meu primeiro projeto e não tenho nenhum conceito sobre o assunto.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi o problema de assinatura sem necessitar items:
Usei e o Pré-aprovado que está no exemplo da pasta dotnet->source->example->preapproval->createPreapproval 
Nisso tive que alterar PreapprovalSerializer.cs  por causa de um problema de data que foi gerado
 
Como explicado pelo [Margatho](http://forum.pagseguro.uol.com.br/t/12789871/preapproval---codigo-funciona-no-sandbox-e-nao-mais-na-producao) adicionei o dateRead

```
namespace Uol.PagSeguro.XmlParse <- NameSpace
internal static class PreApprovalSerializer <- Classe
internal static void Read(XmlReader reader, PreApprovalRequestResponse preApprovalResponse) <- Método

switch (reader.Name)
                    {
                        case PreApprovalSerializer.Date: <- Ini
                            DateTime dateRead;                           
                            DateTime.TryParse(reader.ReadElementContentAsString(), out dateRead);
                            preApprovalResponse.RegistrationDate = dateRead;
                            break; <- fim
                        case PreApprovalSerializer.Code:
                            preApprovalResponse.Code = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                            break;
                        case PreApprovalSerializer.Status:
                            preApprovalResponse.Status = reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                            break;
                        default:
                            XMLParserUtils.SkipElement(reader);
                            break;
                    }
```

Sendo assim foi criado uma assinatura sem produto ! Mas não teria achado esse resultado sem ter entendido a conversa anterior.