# Integração entrando em loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando integrar o PagSeguro à minha aplicação, mas estou encontrando enorme dificuldades, pois são inúmeras informações não detalhadas que encontro pela frente, me deixando cada vez mais confuso.

Eu tenho apenas 1 produto que é vendido por pacote, que no caso serão 3 pacotes diferentes, ao qual o cliente escolherá apenas dos pacotes para efetuar o pagamento, então não necessitaria de um carrinho.

Estou usando este código que o Cigano disponibilizou em [uma das respostas aqui mesmo no SO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/37090/132).

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult NovoPedido(int? id)
        {
            const bool isSandbox = true;
             EnvironmentConfiguration.ChangeEnvironment(isSandbox);

            try
            {
                var credentials = PagSeguroConfiguration.Credentials(isSandbox);

                // Instanciar uma nova requisição de pagamento
                var payment = new PaymentRequest { Currency = Currency.Brl };

                Pacote pacote = db.Pacotes.Find(id);

                // Adicionar produtos
                payment.Items.Add(new Item(Convert.ToString(pacote.PacoteID), pacote.Titulo, 1, pacote.valor));

                int clienteId = Repositorios.Funcoes.GetUsuario().PessoaID;
                Pessoa pessoa= db.Pessoas.Find(clienteId);
                Cidade cidade = db.Cidades.Find(pessoa.CidadeID);
                Estado estado = db.Estados.Find(cidade.EstadoID);
                // Informações de entrega
                payment.Shipping = new Shipping
                {
                    ShippingType = ShippingType.NotSpecified,
                    Cost = 0.00m,
                    Address = new Address(
                        "BRA",
                        estado.Sigla,
                        estado.Nome,
                        cidade.Nome,
                        musico.CEP,
                        musico.Rua,
                        Convert.ToString(pessoa.NResidencia),
                        musico.Complemento
                        )
                };

                // Informações do remetente

                var nome = pessoa.Nome;
                var email = pessoa.Email;
                var celular = pessoa.Celular;
                celular = Regex.Replace(celular, "[^0-9]", "");
                int contador = celular.Count();
                string ddd = celular.Substring(0, 2);
                string numero = celular.Substring(2, (contador - 2));
                payment.Sender = new Sender(
                    nome,
                    email,
                    new Phone(ddd, numero)
                );

                // URL a redirecionar o usuário após pagamento
                payment.RedirectUri = new Uri("http://localhost:50534/Pagamento/Retorno");

                // Informações extras para identificar o pagamento.
                // Essas informações são livres para adicionar o que for necessário.

                var senderCpf = new SenderDocument(Documents.GetDocumentByType("CPF"), musico.CPF);
                payment.Sender.Documents.Add(senderCpf);

                var paymentRedirectUri = payment.Register(credentials);

            Console.WriteLine("URL do pagamento : " + paymentRedirectUri);
                Console.ReadKey();

            }
            catch (PagSeguroServiceException exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception.Message + "\n");

                foreach (var element in exception.Errors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(element + "\n");
                }
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            return View();
        } //fim pedido
```

Alguém sabe o que é esta linha abaixo?

```
Console.WriteLine("URL do pagamento : " + paymentRedirectUri);
```

Pois até esta linha citado abaixo, eu trago as informações corretas. Porém quando chega na linha acima, o site fica num loop de como se tivesse atualizando...

```
SenderDocument(Documents.GetDocumentByType("CPF"), musico.CPF);
payment.Sender.Documents.Add(senderCpf);
```

Comment: Obs: Estou aprendendo asp.net-MVC por isso tenho dificuldades em entender alguns termos mais Técnicos. Se puder deixar a resposta mais claramente possível ficarei Grato

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine("");
```

É um método usado para aplicações do tipo *console* (sujestivo, não?). Ele serve para escrever algo na tela, mostrar algo pro usuário.

O "problema" do seu código não tem nada a ver com o código acima e sim com os **`Console.ReadKey()`**, este método faz a aplicação **esperar por uma entrada do usuário via console**.

Logo, a aplicação **não trava, ela espera por uma entrada via console**.

O código dentro da *action* foi feito pra rodar em *console*. Você precisa atentar para este tipo de coisa, copiar o código e colar dentro da *action* não me parece ser uma forma de fazer funcionar.

Comment: sou novato na área, estou aprendendo ainda. O fato de Copiar e colar o código veio desta [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35093/comunica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-o-pagseguro) seguida da [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35093/comunica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-o-pagseguro/37090#37090) que me pareceu muito óbvia, pois aparentemente se tratava de um site web, então adaptei ao meu sistema da maneira que eu sabia. Obrigado pela resposta, esclareceu minha dúvida.

Comment: se Console.ReadKey() esperaria uma entrada via console, como utilizaria para ser via web?

Comment: Isso não existe! Além de que, é completamente desnecessário...

Answer (score 2):

Esta linha:

```
Console.WriteLine("URL do pagamento : " + paymentRedirectUri);
```

É um teste para escrever em console o retorno da URL que deve ser usada para redirecionar o usuário para o PagSeguro e realizar seu pagamento.

Não fui eu que escrevi esse teste. Foi a equipe da UOL, e ele não deve ser usado para código de produção da forma como está. A ideia é que você apenas consiga ver qual endereço vai voltar dentro de um teste.

O correto, dentro de um `ActionResult`, é usar da seguinte forma:

```
var senderCpf = new SenderDocument(Documents.GetDocumentByType("CPF"), musico.CPF);
payment.Sender.Documents.Add(senderCpf);

var paymentRedirectUri = payment.Register(credentials);

return Redirect(paymentRedirectUri);
```